# Check for the existence of a html element in directive during unit testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I have created a directive "generate-form-field-directive" which will create a form field based on the type received. Below is the code for directive -

```
(function () {
"use strict";

var app = angular.module("appModule");

app.directive("generateFormField", generateFormField);

/*@ngInject*/
function generateFormField() {

    return {
        restrict: "E",

        scope: {
            attributeDetails: "=",
            fieldName: "="
        },

        replace: false,

        controller: function($scope, actionStore) {
            var vm = this;                   
        },

       template: "<div class='col-sm-9 generate-form-field-container'>" +

                    "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='{{fieldName}}' ng-if='attributeDetails.type === \"String\"' ng-model='attributeDetails.value' required>" +
                    "<input type='number' class='form-control' name='{{fieldName}}'' ng-if='attributeDetails.type === \"Integer\"' ng-model='attributeDetails.value' required>" +
                 "</div>"

    };
}

}());
```

So if attributeDetails.type is "String" then the first input tag will be rendered. Same for attributeDetails.type = integer. Now I want to check whether the "input[type=text]" is present in DOM or not when I pass the obkecj - attribute: {
               "type":"String",
               "name": "Name",
               "value": "Volume1"
          }.

The unit test file is -

```
describe("UNIT DIRECTIVE: generateFormField", function () {
"use strict";

// Angular injectables
var $compile, $rootScope, $httpBackend, $q;

// Module defined (non-Angular) injectables
var $scope, generateFormField, actionStore;

// Local variables used for testing
var element, formRequestResponse, directiveScope, vm, template, getListOptions;

// Initialize modules
beforeEach(function () {
    module("appModule");
});

beforeEach(function () {

    inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_, _$q_, _actionStore_) {
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $q = _$q_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();            
    });
});

describe("generateFormField unit testing", function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        template = "<generate-form-field attribute-details='attribute' field-name='key'></generate-form-field>";            
        $scope.attribute = {
           "type":"String",
           "name": "Name",
           "value": "Volume1"
      },

        $scope.key = "volName";
        element = $compile(template)($scope);     

        directiveScope = element.find("generate-form");

        // Exercise SUT
        $scope.$digest();
    });

   **//how to check for input[type=text]**
   it("it should create input button of type='text'", function() {
        //expect(element.html()).indexOf("type='text'").to.not.equal(-1);
        //expect(element("input[type=text]").length).to.be(1);
    });

});
});
```

It will be good if you can provide working fiddle for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40374135/2545680) help?

Comment: @Maximus Thanks :)

Comment: you're welcome, you can accept it if it solved your problem)

Answer (score 1):

After running this code:

```
element = $compile(template)($scope);
```

You should be able to find your input:

```
var input = element[0].querySelector("input[type=text]");
```